# Optimising a simple equation for execution speed in C++

Tags: c++, performance

I am working on a program where speed is really important since everything is in a loop. I wanted to know which one of these two equations is faster to execute.

The first one is:

```
smoothing / (1 + smoothing)
```

where `smoothing` is a `const unsigned int`.

The second one would be:

```
1-1/(1+smoothing)
```

Will the first one be faster since there is less operators involved in the equation? Will the second one be faster become `smoothing` is only called one time? Is there another option that is faster than these two?

Comment: Did you try timing them both to test?

Comment: The division is the performance killer.  Can you eliminate or reduce the quantity of divisions?

Comment: The expressions are not equivalent. The first yields 0, while the second yields 1. First make the code correct, only then try to measure to find out where to optimize, or whether that's necessary.

Comment: Show more of your code. Chances are that the other code in the loop offers more optimisation potential than this expression.

Comment: @scohe001 Any except 0, as long as it is in unsigned int.

Comment: do you want floating-point division or integer-division? (it seems you want floating otherwise they are constant as in JimB's answer)

Comment: Even if done in float, the calculation, based on a const whatever, can be taken out of the loop. You must have left out something. Please show and explain more of your code.

Comment: For the record, in a compiled language like C++, referencing `smoothing` once or twice scarcely matters; unless you've completely disabled optimizations, any compiler worth its salt would be caching `smoothing` in a register, where the access times are significantly faster than the math itself (which is already blazing fast). Loading a value from a register once vs. twice is meaningless. Microoptimizations like that do nothing in a compiled language, and even in a high-level dynamic language like Python the difference is usually trivial.

Comment: to be precise `smoothing / (1 + smoothing)` will return divide-by-0 error when `smoothing == UINT_MAX` and 0 otherwise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the expressions as-is will produce a 0 or a 1, respectively, due to integer arithmetic (whatever floating point result you may have expected will be lost). This can be solved by using floating point literals in your expression (e.g. `smoothing / (1.0f + smoothing)`), which will produce a floating point result.

That aside, you shouldn't worry too much over manual optimization at this level. Your compiler is able to optimize equivalent expressions on its own; your focus should be on writing what is most readable to you as a programmer.

If you fix the floating point issue mentioned above, gcc 7.2 produces equivalent assembly for both expressions, and that's with optimization *disabled*. So there's nothing to worry about. They're both just as "fast".

As well, if `smoothing` is indeed constant, the result of your expression is also constant, and does not need to be recalculated with every iteration of the loop. You can simply declare another constant variable whose value is the result of the expression.